# Least Action with Local Equilibrium

Tags: statistical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, variational-principle

I am looking for help to taking a multi-particle system and defining a local equilibrium so that I can get a variational principle for the slightly simplified system.

For example, if I have the system,

\begin{align}
S &= \int dt \sum_i \mathcal{L}(q_i, \dot{q}_i) \\
  &= \int dt\ d^3x \sum_i \delta(q_i - x) \mathcal{L}(q_i, \dot{q}_i) \\
  &= \sum_{\mathbb{B}_n} \int_{\mathbb{B}_n} dt\ d^3x \sum_i \delta(q_i - x) \mathcal{L}(q_i, \dot{q}_i)
\end{align}

Then for each box $ \mathbb{B}_n $ I would approximate with the system being in local equilibrium and take the Stat Mech approach to writing the equilibrium system equation for each box.

My concern is that I wouldn't know how to write the local equilibrium Lagrangian to replace the $ \int_{\mathbb{B}_n} dt\ d^3x \sum_i \delta(q_i - x) \mathcal{L}(q_i, \dot{q}_i) $.

I read [A Lagrangian formalism for nonequilibrium thermodynamics](https://arxiv.org/abs/1510.00792), but I am not entirely sure how to stick the Lagrangian into the action above because the state variables change.

Can you give me a reference or the next step with this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will explain this in the order that you might want to read about it as opposed to the logical order, then again in logical order.

**Variational Principle for Hamiltonian Fluids**

From ["Hamiltonian Fluid Dynamics" by P. J. Morrison](http://web2.ph.utexas.edu/~morrison/06EMP_morrison.pdf), we learn how to write the variational form of fluid equations. We use Lagrangian coordinates and write the action as,

\begin{align}
S[q] &= \int dt\ L[q, \dot{q}] \\
  &= \int dt\ d^3a\ \left[ \frac{1}{2} \rho_0 \dot{q}^2 - \rho_0 U(\rho, s) \right]
\end{align}
where coordinates $ a = q(t=0) $, density $ \rho_0 = \rho(t=0) $ and $ U(\rho, s) $ is the [thermodynamic internal energy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internal_energy) transformed to use density instead of volume (see [Specific Volume](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specific_volume)).

**Local Equilibrium**

From ["Equilibrium Statistical Mechanics" by Plischke](http://home.basu.ac.ir/~psu/Books/Equilibrium%20Statistical%20Physics%20(3rd%20Edition)-M.%20Plischke%20&%20B.%20Bergesen.pdf), we can compute the internal energy from the microcanonical ensemble.

\begin{align}
\Omega(E, V, N) &= \frac{1}{h^{3N} N!} \int_{E < \mathcal{H}(x, p) \leq E + \delta E} d^{3N}x\ d^{3N}p \\
S(E, V, N) &= k_B \log \Omega(E, V, N) \\
S_{\text{ideal gas}} &= N k_B \log \frac{V}{N} + \frac{3N}{2} k_B \log \frac{4 \pi m E}{3 N h^2} + \frac{5}{2} N k_B
\end{align}

For use in the Hamiltonian from Morrison, we actually want to transform the variables a bit, Morrison uses these transformations and yield the following properties,
\begin{align}
U &= \frac{E}{mN} ;\ \ \rho = \frac{mN}{V} ;\ \ s = \frac{S}{mN} \\
\frac{\partial U}{\partial \rho} &= \frac{1}{mN} \frac{\partial E}{\partial V} \frac{\partial V}{\partial \rho} = \frac{1}{mN} (-p) \frac{-mN}{\rho^2} = \frac{p}{\rho^2} \\
\frac{\partial U}{\partial s} &= \frac{1}{mN} \frac{\partial E}{\partial S} \frac{\partial S}{\partial s} = \frac{1}{mN} (T) mN = T
\end{align}

which Morrison claims in his paper.

**Many-body to Fluid**

The many body action would look like,
\begin{align}
S[q_i] &= \int dt \sum_i L(q_i, \dot{q}_i) \\
  &= \int dt\ d^3a\ \rho_0(a)\ L(q(a), \dot{q}(a)) \\
  &= \int dt\ d^3a\ \rho_0\ \left( p \frac{\partial \mathcal{H}}{\partial p} - \mathcal{H} \right) \\
\end{align}
where $ a $ has just become our continuum label and we assume that there are many particles in each region of label-space $ d^3a $ so we can make an equilibrium approximation.

Now, we break our dynamics up into average "large-scale" dynamics and local dynamics which shall be claimed to be in equilibrium. Frankly, I am not sure of how to do this super formally, so I invoke the physicist right of hand-waving!

\begin{align}
\mathcal{H}(q, p) = \mathcal{H}_{avg}(\bar{q}, \bar{p}) + \mathcal{H}_{equil}(\Delta q, \Delta p)
\end{align}
where $ \mathcal{H}_{equil} $ could be computed with a Taylor series, but we can opt for an easier method. Simply compute the density of states for $ \mathcal{H}_{equil}(\Delta q, \Delta p) = \mathcal{H}(\bar{q} + \Delta q, \bar{p} + \Delta p) - \mathcal{H}_{avg}(\bar{q}, \bar{p}) $.

\begin{align}
\Omega(E, V, N) &= \frac{1}{h^{3N} N!} \int_{E < \mathcal{H}_{equil}(\Delta q, \Delta p) \leq E + \delta E} d^{3N}\Delta q\ d^{3N} \Delta p \\
\end{align}
which is just the normal density of states for our system with phase space coordinate translations and a gauge shift. Normal physical systems ought to be invariant to both.

Thus our final Hamiltonian can be taken as,
\begin{align}
\mathcal{H}(q, p) \rightarrow \mathcal{H}(q, p) + U(\rho, s)
\end{align}
where I dropped the over-bar denoting averages and $ U $ is computed as above.

Noting that $ \rho_0 d^3a = \rho d^3q $, we find our action to be,
\begin{align}
S &= \int dt\ d^3a\ \rho_0\ \left( p \frac{\partial \mathcal{H}}{\partial p} - \mathcal{H}(q, p) - U(\rho, s) \right) \\
  &= \int dt\ d^3a\ \rho_0\ \left( \mathcal{L} - U(\rho, s) \right) \\
  &= \int dt\ d^3q\ \rho \left( \mathcal{L} - U(\rho, s) \right)
\end{align}

which reproduces Morrison's results. In practicing using this formalism, it seems that best practice is to treat $ q(a, t) $ as field activation and do the variation on field coordinates $ (a, t) $ (ie. using $ \int dt\ d^3a $ version). For example, see below.

**Ideal Gas**

As an example, we get the equations for an ideal gas. From previous definitions,
\begin{align}
s &= \frac{k_B}{m} \log m \rho + \frac{3}{2m} k_B \log \frac{4 \pi m^2 U}{2 h^2} + \frac{5 k_B}{2m} \\
U &= c \rho^{\gamma - 1} e^{\alpha s} = \left[\frac{h^{2} e^{- \frac{5}{3}}}{2 \pi m^{\frac{8}{3}}} \right] \rho^{\frac{1}{3}-1} e^{\frac{2 m}{3 k}s}\\
S &= \int dt\ d^3a\ \rho_0 \left( \frac{1}{2} \dot{q}^2 - U \right)
\end{align}

With [uniform density](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_equations_(fluid_dynamics)#Incompressible_Euler_equations_with_constant_and_uniform_density) (ie. $ \nabla \rho_0 = 0 $) and the Jacobian $ \mathcal{J} = \frac{d^3q}{d^3a} $,
\begin{align}
\delta S &= \int dt\ d^3a\ \left[ \rho_0 \dot{q}_i \delta \dot{q}_i - \rho_0 \left( \frac{\partial U}{\partial \rho} \delta \rho + \frac{\partial U}{\partial s} \delta s \right) \right] \\
  &= \int dt\ d^3a\ \left[ -\rho_0 \ddot{q}_i \delta q_i - \rho_0^2  \frac{\partial U}{\partial \rho} \frac{\partial \frac{1}{\mathcal{J}}}{\partial \frac{\partial q^k}{\partial a^j}} \delta \frac{\partial q^k}{\partial a^j} \right] \\
  &= \int dt\ d^3a\ \left[ -\rho_0 \ddot{q}_k - \frac{\partial}{\partial a^j} \left( \rho^2 \frac{\partial U}{\partial \rho} \frac{\partial \mathcal{J}}{\partial \frac{\partial q^k}{\partial a^j}} \right) \right] \delta q_k \\
\end{align}
which reproduces Morrison. More details shown [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/339031/help-me-understand-the-skipped-steps-regarding-hamiltonian-fluids/339208#339208).